# File open and close in python

Tags: python, file, with-statement, contextmanager

I have read that when file is opened using the below format

```
with open(filename) as f:
       #My Code
f.close()
```

explicit closing of file is not required . Can someone explain why is it so ? Also if someone does explicitly close the file, will it have any undesirable effect ?

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: I deleted the tag ``python-2.7`` because the with statement isn't specific to this version of Python. The with statement was introduced in Python 2.5 and is since then a fundamental feature of Python. An intersting blog's page on this subject is here: (http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The mile-high overview is this: When you leave the nested block, Python automatically calls `f.close()` for you.

It doesn't matter whether you leave by just falling off the bottom, or calling `break`/`continue`/`return` to jump out of it, or raise an exception; no matter how you leave that block. It *always* knows you're leaving, so it *always* closes the file.*

---

One level down, you can think of it as mapping to the `try:`/`finally:` statement:

```
f = open(filename)
try:
    # My Code
finally:
    f.close()
```

---

One level down: How does it know to call `close` instead of something different?

Well, it doesn't really. It actually calls special methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`:

```
f = open()
f.__enter__()
try:
    # My Code
finally:
    f.__exit__()
```

And the object returned by `open` (a `file` in Python 2, one of the wrappers in `io` in Python 3) has something like this in it:

```
def __exit__(self):
    self.close()
```

---

It's actually a bit more complicated than that last version, which makes it easier to generate better error messages, and lets Python avoid "entering" a block that it doesn't know how to "exit".

To understand all the details, read [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).

---

> Also if someone does explicitly close the file, will it have any undesirable effect ?

In general, this is a bad thing to do.

However, file objects go out of their way to make it safe. It's an error to do anything to a closed file—except to `close` it again.

---

* Unless you leave by, say, pulling the power cord on the server in the middle of it executing your script. In that case, obviously, it never gets to run *any* code, much less the `close`. But an explicit `close` would hardly help you there.

Answer (score 3):

Closing is not required because the `with` statement automatically takes care of that.

Within the `with` statement the `__enter__` method on `open(...)` is called and as soon as you go out of that block the `__exit__` method is called.

So closing it manually is just futile since the `__exit__` method will take care of that automatically.

As for the `f.close()` after, it's not wrong but useless. It's already closed so it won't do anything.

Also see this blogpost for more info about the `with` statement: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm