# When it is required to close a file in Python?

Tags: python, file

Say I have the following code:

```
remote = urlopen('www...../file.txt')
with open(file='file', mode='wb') as local:
    local.write(remote.read())
```

Do I need to also do:

```
local.close()
remote.close()
```

How do I know when `close()` is needed and when Python takes care of it for me?

Comment: when you open the file using `with`, python takes care of it.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459867/file-open-and-close-in-python

Comment: @ConsistentProgrammer and what about the urlopen?

Comment: @Luis: I only wanted to share information regarding file open/close

Comment: @Luis Use `with` for that as well, and it will be done automatically.

Comment: What does the python documentation say about `urlopen`?

Comment: @Barmar you mean nested withs?

Comment: You can have multiple `with` on the same line. `with urlopen(...) as remote, open(...) as local:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a context manager ( which is what the "with.." statement is) then you don't need to use the `.close`.

Python manages the resources for you in this case. [This](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) is a good article that goes into the detail of how it works.

Its good practice to use context managers whenever possible, and you can create your own using the [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to close the file explicitly when you are using python `with` statement. So you are good with `local` object. And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522636/should-i-call-close-after-urllib-urlopen) explains why you should close the `remote` resource explicitly.