# How to close a file after reading it in a function

Tags: python, file, python-re

I've got a function that reads a text file and saves all the words into a variable. Someone told me that I should close the file after reading it but I'm not sure how to do it especially when I'm using a function.

```
import re

def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        words = []
        
        for line in lines:
            words += re.findall(r'\w+', line.lower())
            
    return words
```

Comment: This someone is right to tell you to close a file after reading it. However, the code you present to us goes one better and guarantees to you that the file will be closed after you have used it.

Comment: This Question already has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459867/file-open-and-close-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is closed due to the `with` statement. There is 2 ways to use files:

```
f = open(...)
# do stuff
f.close()
```

Or, preferred and as you have done:

```
with open(...) as f:
  # do stuff
# file is closed once the do stuff block ends
```

The code above works because of 2 magic functions (magic functions are functions used by the compiler like `__str__` that have special meaning)

`__enter__` and `__exit__`.
These are used by the `with` block like this:

```py
with some as f:
  # stuff
```

Means the same thing as:

```py
f = some.__enter__()
# stuff
some.__exit__()
```

Answer (score 2):

The file is closed as soon as the `with` block that opened it is exited.